# How to capture date of event X and then capture the date of an event that happens after event X

Tags: mysql

So I am working with event data.

I need to identify when "X happens", store that data in a column and then identify when "in-production" happens.
Now, I just want the first "in-production" that shows up after "X happens" I do not care about the previous ones.
Note: Between "X happens" and "in-production" happens multiple states can exist.

What have I tried: case whens, self joins, with tables... nothing to my avail.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks a lot friends!

```
TblEvents  
=========
 EventID OrderID EventDate       Status  
       1       2 01/02/2011      in-production
       2       2 02/02/2011      pending
       3       2 03/02/2011      on-hold
       4       2 03/02/2011      stuck
       5       2 03/02/2011      *X happens*
       6       2 04/02/2011      pending
       7       2 05/02/2011      *in-production*
```

```
Output table:

date of event X | date of "in-production"
03/02/2011        05/02/2011
```

Comment: Is [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aZmroiAUrhzpeorou46PXn/1) what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    OuterTblEvents.EventDate AS 'date of event X',
    (
        SELECT EventDate
        FROM TblEvents
        WHERE
            TblEvents.Status = 'in-production'
            AND TblEvents.EventID > OuterTblEvents.EventID
        ORDER BY TblEvents.EventID
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS 'date of "in-production"'
FROM TblEvents OuterTblEvents
WHERE OuterTblEvents.Status = 'X happens'
```

Though note that if the table is large and/or you run this often - performance may suffer, because the inner query is invoked once per each row that is found in the outer query.

Also, a composite index on `Status, EventID` should make both the outer and inner queries more performant. The outer query would use only the `Status` part of the index, and the inner query would use both `Status` and `EventID`. Note that the order of the columns in this composite index matters.